# iOS, PHP and mySQL. Display data from a database on Iphone

Tags: php, mysql, ios

Hi ya'll I am building an app and I trying to get data to display on my app via MySQL and PHP.

I have looked at some tutorials and I tried to make sense of them and this what I have come up with...

This is my php file which is located on my server GetData.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("myhostingserver", "username", "password", "database");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, CASE open when 1 then 'Yes' when 0 then 'No' END as open, date, time, extra1, extra2, lastUpdated FROM MyTable");
```

and this is what I put on my ViewController.h file in xcode

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *YesOrNo;

@end
```

and this is the code from my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myhostingserver.com/GetData.php"];

    // to execute php code
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    // to receive the returend value
    NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_YesOrNo release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I think this seems right, but how do I get the data of open in the textbox?

would it be something along the lines of `*YesOrNow = *strResult['open']`?

I ran my app with the code above, no errors just a warning that says *strResult is an unused variable...please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the text of the `YesOrNo` label to the `strResult` variable you created from the network script:
`self.YesOrNo.text = strResult;`

Seems that you're jumping very quickly into app and server interactions.  slow down and learn about PHP, and Objectice-C/Cocoa-touch separately so you can more easily identify what to do and debug on your own.  i'd say this question is somewhat a waste and such a problem would normally be solved given basic knowledge of application(ios) development

Comment: First I had to have my php files echo out the value and then I applied `self.YesOrNo.text = strResult;` and it worked! My question is I am planing on having more than one label that I will want to display more data from the sql select statment `$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, CASE open when 1 then 'Yes' when 0 then 'No' END as open, date, time, extra1, extra2, lastUpdated FROM MyTable");`

Comment: Is there away to pick which data I want from the sql statement like `self.YesOrNo.text = strResult['open']` or `self.YesOrNo.text = strResult['lastUpdated']` or will I have to write a new php file for each data I want to display?

Comment: @user2499454 use a dictionary to contain the value you get from the server, then for each label, assign the value from your dictionary to it.